# How to use Phone Modem with smstools3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, mount, telephony, modem, sms-gateway

### I have installed smstools3 on ubuntu and my smsd.conf have the following settings.

devices = GSM1
loglevel = 7
outgoing = /var/spool/sms/outgoing
failed = /var/spool/sms/failed
incoming = /var/spool/sms/incoming
sent = /var/spool/sms/sent
logfile = /var/log/smsd.log
delaytime = 1
errorsleeptime = 2
blocktime = 3600

[GSM1]
device = **/dev/sdb**
incoming = yes
mode = new
baudrate = 19200
cs_convert = yes
report = no

### The problem is that I am not able to find as to which port "/dev/ttyUSB*", my Phone Modem is connected so that I can fill it opposite to device and use it.

Following is the output of lsusb and mount command.
/var/spool/sms/outgoing$ **lsusb**
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 12d1:140b Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:181c Ricoh Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 018: ID 0fce:d144 **Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB** 

eguamak@CTM2WS1:/var/spool/sms/outgoing$

---------------------------------
eguamak@CTM2WS1:/var/spool/sms/outgoing$ **mount** 
/dev/mapper/my_vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/eguamak/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon 
(rw,nosuid,nodev,user=eguamak)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)

**I am trying to use Sony Ericsson Phone as Modem.

Please Suggest as how to Mount my phone correctly so that I can use it as GSM Modem with smstools3.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing a couple of of issues here. When the phone is connected to the PC it can operate in several different (USB) modes, and therefore it will ask the user what type of operation it should use. There are a couple of those modes, but let's focus on *USB Mass storage* and *USB ACM CDC*.

For mass storage the phone exports its internal flash memory and possibly also its memory card if there is one and that is all the phone is doing in this mode, e.g. there is no serial port access. In this case you will get new devices like `/dev/sdb` and you use the mount command to access the file system on the phone. The content of /var/log/messages should look something like the following:

```
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost kernel: [2338445.838575] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost kernel: [2338446.232227] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fce, idProduct=e0d9
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost kernel: [2338446.232235] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost kernel: [2338446.232239] usb 3-1: Product: Memory Stick
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost kernel: [2338446.232242] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Sony Ericsson
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost kernel: [2338446.232245] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 3577870222208500
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/usb3/3-1"
Apr 29 23:35:52 localhost mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Apr 29 23:35:53 localhost kernel: [2338446.707832] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
Apr 29 23:35:53 localhost kernel: [2338446.707948] scsi5 : usb-storage 3-1:2.0
Apr 29 23:35:53 localhost kernel: [2338446.708029] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Apr 29 23:35:53 localhost kernel: [2338446.708030] USB Mass Storage support registered.
Apr 29 23:35:54 localhost kernel: [2338447.709323] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sony Eri Memory Stick        0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Apr 29 23:35:54 localhost kernel: [2338447.709745] scsi 5:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Sony Eri Memory Stick        0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Apr 29 23:35:54 localhost kernel: [2338447.712336] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Apr 29 23:35:54 localhost kernel: [2338447.712626] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Apr 29 23:35:54 localhost kernel: [2338447.715373] sd 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Apr 29 23:35:54 localhost kernel: [2338447.716468] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.100623] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] 31252482 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.101044] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 368494 512-byte logical blocks: (188 MB/179 MiB)
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.102609] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.103824] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.105068] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.105071] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.106083] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.106087] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.108251] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.109471] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.109475] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.110339] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.114310] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.114320] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.117898]  sdc: sdc1
Apr 29 23:36:02 localhost kernel: [2338456.126606]  sdb: sdb1
```

However, for use with smstools you are interested in the mode called CDC, and then you will get the devices `/dev/ttyACM0` and `/dev/ttyACM1` which the tool will access as serial devices (and the mount command is not used at all for this).
The content of /var/log/messages should look something like the following:

```
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.833163] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.864341] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fce, idProduct=d0d9
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.864350] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.864355] usb 3-1: Product: Sony Ericsson C702
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.864359] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Sony Ericsson
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.864362] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 3577870222208500
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.871215] cdc_acm 3-1:3.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.874835] cdc_acm 3-1:3.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.879449] cdc_wdm 3-1:3.7: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
Apr 29 23:34:48 localhost kernel: [2338381.882332] cdc_ether 3-1:3.8 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:02:00.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:80:37:0a:03:00
```

So when you connect the USB cable to the pc, you must select the option "phone mode" or whatever it is called (not mass storage, not media transfer something nor print something).

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion, However I connected my phone via bluetooth and it works fine